# Webservice doens't working on fresh install

Tags: prestashop

After performing a fresh install of [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/) ( v 1.6.0.9 ) i've encountered some problems about making the webservice feature avaliable.

I have set the key and i'm able to check the ws's avaliable using the url

http://example.com/webservice/dispatcher.php?ws_key=my_key

And 3 of the relevant result's are:

http://example.com/api/employees?schema=synopsis

http://example.com/api/employees

http://example.com/api/employees?schema=blank

So, testing the links above,i receive the message **This page is not available** right into my face, i'm not sure why this behaviour.

For aditional information, i followed the steps on the [Web Service Tutorial](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial)  where i downloaded the PSWebServiceLibrary.php file into my root folder, i also created a test file with the content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: thales.pereira
 * Date: 05/01/15
 * Time: 16:10
 */
require_once( './PSWebServiceLibrary.php' );

$shop_url="http://localhost";
$secret_key="the_key";
$debug=false;
try {
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($shop_url, $secret_key, $debug);

    $opt['resource'] = 'customers?schema=synopsis';
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);
    echo $xml;
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

But well.. the result was:

```
Other error:
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 404.
That means: Not Found.
```

For this dev environment, i'm using MAMP Version 3.0.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was with nginx regex rules.

Here is what is currently working for me:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  access_log   /var/log/nginx/prestashop.access.log;
  error_log    /var/log/nginx/prestashop.error.log;
  root /var/www/prestashop;

  if ($http_host != "127.0.0.1") {
    rewrite ^ http://127.0.0.1$request_uri permanent;
  }

  index index.php index.html;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).

  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
  rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

  error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

  location ~* \.(gif)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(png)$ {
    expires 2592000s;
  }

  location ~* \.(css)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(js)$ {
    expires 604800s;
  }

  location ~* \.(ico)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }

}
```